# Is it possible to install a chosen version of Linux Mint in a Docker container?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, docker

I am a beginner at Docker on WSL2.

I am working on a project that was built entirely on Linux Mint 19.2. To be fully aligned with the project, I try to run a docker container with that OS.

I am thinking of something at the start of the Dockerfile like:

```
FROM mint:19.2
```

This base image does not exist, of course:

> manifest for mint:19.2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Is it at all possible to install Linux Mint in a container, at best with version 19.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux-Mint images are offered at https://hub.docker.com/r/vcatechnology/linux-mint.

And how would you integrate that in a Dockerfile? Just running `docker pull vcatechnology/linux-mint` there gives `docker image build ~; Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.87kB; Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 13: unknown instruction: DOCKER`.

The solution is: `FROM vcatechnology/linux-mint:<version>`.

The version 19.2 is not available: `FROM vcatechnology/linux-mint:19.2` gives `invalid reference format`. Version 19 is not part of the [listed tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/vcatechnology/linux-mint/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated). Use for example version 18 which was the base for version 19 anyway (or rather use 18.2 then).